# Сравнение строк по алфавиту

Tags: c++, c, строки

У меня есть список структуры, в которой есть поле string, я хочу два элемента структуры сравнить согласно алфавиту(для сортировки), а если быть точнее, то первым должно быть слово, первая буква которого в алфавите находится раньше, если же они одинаковые, то сравниваем по второй букве и так далее. Подскажите какой функцией я могу воспользоваться.

Comment: где ваш пример реализации?

Comment: Просто сравнить две строки через `<`?

Comment: [strcmp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html)

Comment: Уточните, это `C` или `C++`? Ответы будут очень разные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос, на самом деле, совсем не простой. Если Ваши **строки** содержат только 7-битные символы ASCII, то проще всего воспользоваться стандарной функцией *strcmp()*.

Однако, если в эти строки входят какие-то другие символы, то для сравнения необходимо знать способ кодирования этих "других" симвлов. И здесь всё плохо. Способов кодирования много, таблиц кодировок ещё больше и проблема перестаёт иметь однозначное решение.

Теоретически, по стандарту POSIX, если Вы правильно указали *locale*, то функция *strcmp()* должна работать правильно. Однако это остаётся на совести разработчика ОС.

Согласно POSIX, сведения из локали используют функци strcoll(), strxfrm() и некоторые другие.

> Функция  strcoll()  сравнивает  строки  s1  и s2. Она возвращает целое
> число, которое может быть меньше,  равно  или  больше  ноля,  если
> выяснится,  что  s1  меньше,  равна  или   больше   s2 соответственно.
> Сравнение  производится  на основе правил текущей локали, указанной в
> категории

```
       LC_COLLATE (см. setlocale(3)).
```

Ситуация несколько упрощается, если используется кодировка UTF-8. Её не нужно подстраивать под конкретную локаль, она универсальная.

Ну, если Вы пишите для Linux, то можете использовать эту библиотеку для работы с UTF-8:

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html

Там есть всё :-)

Comment: Кажется, вопрос был про `C++`, а там всё проще. Я вижу оба тега `C` и `C++`,  но прямое упоминание `string` указывает на `C++`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ЯП тут многому не поможет, разве в Си++ научились сравнивать любые символы Юникода? Или лигатуры учитывать стали для всех возможных вариаций? Это есть в прошлогоднем стандарте?

Comment: 1. Unicode в вопросе не упоминался. `string::operator <` - проще чем `strcmp`.
2. `wstring::operator <` решает проблему для Unicode.